# Equivalent of PHP XMLREADER::ELEMENT $reader->depth in .NET

Tags: php, .net, xml

What would be the equivalent of

PHP XMLREADER::ELEMENT
$reader->depth
 in .NET?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. Could you specify what exactly do you need? The depth of an XML element? And why do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure this is what you want, but .Net's `XmlReader` has the [`Depth` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.depth.aspx) too.